# What is the importance of "pre" in nodejs version v0.6.21-pre?

Tags: node.js

Some versions are having "-pre" at the end of version number and some are not having.
What is the importance of "-pre"?

Comment: I think they just forgot to rename it before release?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means the binary was built from a development or "preview" commit.

From [`src/node_version.h`](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/src/node_version.h):

```
#if NODE_VERSION_IS_RELEASE
# define NODE_VERSION_STRING  NODE_STRINGIFY(NODE_MAJOR_VERSION) "." \
                              NODE_STRINGIFY(NODE_MINOR_VERSION) "." \
                              NODE_STRINGIFY(NODE_PATCH_VERSION)
#else
# define NODE_VERSION_STRING  NODE_STRINGIFY(NODE_MAJOR_VERSION) "." \
                              NODE_STRINGIFY(NODE_MINOR_VERSION) "." \
                              NODE_STRINGIFY(NODE_PATCH_VERSION) "-pre"
#endif
```

The `-pre` is removed for releases (ex: [*2012.08.03 Version 0.6.21 (maintenance)*](https://github.com/joyent/node/commit/v0.6.21#diff-1)) and added again with the subsequent version bump (ex: [*now working on 0.6.22*](https://github.com/joyent/node/commit/2dcaef6efa13242cff9fc5ac9938e2912d2c0ace#diff-0)).